# How to replace values in selected rows columns with an array in dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'A': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],
                       'B': [10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80]})
    A   B
0   1   10
1   2   20
2   3   30
3   4   40
4   5   50
5   6   60
6   7   70
7   8   80
```

which I selected a few rows from. 
Then I have a dictionary containig values that I should insert in `B` column
if key matches with value in `A` column of `df`

```
my_dict = {2: 39622884,
           4: 82709546,
           5: 28166511,
           7: 89465652}
```

When I use the following assignment

```
df.loc[df['A'].isin(my_dict.keys())]['B'] = list(my_dict.values())
```

I get the error:
**ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index**

The desirable output is

```
    A   B
0   1   10
1   2   39622884
2   3   30
3   4   82709546
4   5   50
5   6   28166511
6   7   89465652
7   8   80
```

What is the correct way to implement this procedure?

Comment: @QuangHoang solution is the way I would have done it.  But, I think this fixes your problem.  `df.loc[df['A'].isin(my_dict.keys()), 'B'] = list(my_dict.values())`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make do with `map` and `fillna`:

```
df['B'] = df['A'].map(my_dict).fillna(df['B'])
```

Output:

```
   A           B
0  1        10.0
1  2  39622884.0
2  3        30.0
3  4  82709546.0
4  5  28166511.0
5  6        60.0
6  7  89465652.0
7  8        80.0
```